# Need to touch a file in several directories using one liner in linux

Tags: linux, shell, xargs

I have lots of directories. I need to `cd` to all the directories and create 2 files. I tried doing this using xargs, but I couldn't do it. Can you please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: do you have those two files ? are these two files same for all folders?

Comment: @Prince: Yes.. I have only two files and it will be same

Comment: empty file or having content in it? can you share the name of the files

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want or need to run `find` but have a list of directories, something like this:

```
xargs -i touch {}/a {}/b <directories.txt
```

If the directory paths are completely regular (e.g. all subdirectories two levels down), it might be as easy as

```
touch */*/a */*/b
```

Comment: Thanks.. That worked.. Now one more doubt.. sorry to trouble.. I need to cd to all the sub directories in a directory and execute this command "smt pull"..

Comment: Probably you should post a separate question.  `for d in */.; do ( cd "$d"; smt pull ) done`

Answer (score 1):

```
   find <path> -type d -exec touch {}/a {}/b \;
```

path may be . if you are already in the top directory you are interested to work on.

Comment: This is from bash with find from GNU findutils

Comment: typo... failed to pass the path

Comment: In my find version you don't need to pass the path, the default is the current one. I can anyone edit it.

Comment: At least on Linux it defaults to `.` if you don't supply one.

Comment: @tripleee: Atleast i don't know this fact.

Comment: GNU find defaults to `.` if you do not specify a path, but most finds require a path to be specified (this is standard). For portability a path should always be used.